# Unable to apply patch with nested directories

Tags: linux, patch

I am trying to create simple patch but file is in different directory.

My Directory structure is:

```
/-|hello_new.c
  |-1/-|
       |-2/-|
            |-3/hello.c

//hello_new.c:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        printf("Hello World\n");
}

//hello.c:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

I create the patch using:

```
diff -u 1/2/3/hello.c hello_new.c > hello.patch
```

My patch file is hello.patch:

```
--- 1/2/3/hello.c       2016-02-09 13:31:04.904763020 +0530
+++ hello_new.c 2016-02-08 18:35:47.299940190 +0530
@@ -1,6 +1,5 @@
 #include <stdio.h>

-int main()
-{
+int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        printf("Hello World\n");
 }
```

Now I apply patch using:

```
patch < hello.patch
```

But I get `patching file hello_new.c`
Reversed patch detected.

Answer (score 1):

You would solve this using the [`-p` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/patch-Options.html) of `patch`:

> `-p` *number*
>   `--strip=`*number*
>       Set the file name strip count to *number*. See [patch Directories](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/patch-Directories.html#patch-Directories).

If the before/after levels in your patch-file differ, keep in mind that `patch` gives precedence to the number of levels in the *before* part (the first line of the header).  So you could do

```
patch -p3 < hello.patch
```

to avoid the reversed-patch issue for this instance.

This being GNU patch, you can preview the result by adding the `--dry-run` option (to avoid the nuisance of giving correct responses to the reversed-patch message):

```
$ patch -p3 --dry-run < hello.patch
patching file hello.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 2 with fuzz 2 (offset 1 line).
```

When testing patches, e.g., if they did not match *exactly* (such as tab/space conversion, carriage-return line-endings), I preview patches, and may add a `-l` option to help `patch` make fewer rejects.

Comment: I did that, then it asks me file to apply patch. I had to specify 1/2/3/hello.c again as input. Then it applies this patch. Can it be done without the patch asking for further inputs... Because I want to add this command in a build system.

Comment: @Littleboy most likely you need `--directory` option as well.

Comment: Probably not: I applied the patch without needing the option.